# How to store the function's returns on a button click?

Tags: python, function, button, tkinter, return

In my program, when a button is clicked a function is executed and runs completely fine, but it's return statements seems to be quite pointless because they don't store anything. That is the issue.

This is the program;

```
button1 = Button(loginPage,text = "Login", fg = "red", command = lambda : loginClicked(username.get(), password.get()))
```

and the functions return statement looks like this;

```
return loggedIn,userID
```

I know that the function runs because of print statements in it.

Because the function can only be run when inputs have been inputted on the Tkinter user interface and the button is clicked, how would it be possible for the returned results from the function to be stored for later use in the program.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the use of `lambda`, and simply call a function. I see people use `lambda` all the time with tkinter when it's not needed `lambda` has it's uses, but in this case all it's doing is making the code harder to read and harder to maintain. As a good rule of thumb, a button or binding should always call a function.

It then becomes much easier to see how to do this, either with a global variable, a class, a database, or anything else.

```
def loginClicked():
    global loggedIn, userID

    name = username.get()
    pw = password.get()

    <do the login>

    loggedIn = True
    userID = name


button1 = Button(..., command = loginClicked)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use any data structure in order to store those variables.

For example, you can use two variables that you defined earlier as globals.

```
loggedIn = None
userID = None

def loginClicked(username, password):
    global loggedIn
    global userID
    loggedIn,userID = username, password

button1 = Button(loginPage,text = "Login", fg = "red", command = lambda : loginClicked(username.get(), password.get()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by defining a mutable variable in the global scope and storing the values in it from inside the functions.